# Would it be possible to mine the metallic hydrogen from jupiter with our current technology?

Tags: science-based, physics, economy, space-constructs, astrophysics

Simply put, metallic hydrogen is obtained at absurd atmospheric pressures, becoming a **stable** liquid with very interesting properties. As a super conductor or simply the most efficient fuel that humanity could use, increasing the rocket load capacity and enabling portable fusion reactors.

"Why Metallic Hydrogen is so important! [2020]"
https://youtu.be/LMpdK1NeNTI

Well, obviously, it is stupidly difficult to produce this material in the laboratory. And so far, the research and experiments that claim to have managed to create this material in the laboratory are still seen as questionable.
Needless to say, it would be even more difficult to mass produce this material.

So, what would be left would be to extract this material from somewhere. Obviously, there is no metallic hydrogen on earth. The closest places are Jupiter and Saturn (in relation to Saturn, it is not known exactly if it exists there), which in itself would be difficult to achieve.

However, although metallic hydrogen is not necessarily in Jupiter's core, it would still be absurdly difficult to achieve this layer.

[image: Jupiter and Saturn interiors]

The "best" idea I had would be to make a hose out of carbon nanotubes...

Comment: Short answer: no. I might see about cobbling together a longer answer later, if people haven't already made my points for me ;-)

Comment: Mine it from Jupiter and then do *what* with it? Metallic hydrogen can exist only under enormous pressures. In what kind of container do you plan to store it?

Comment: @AlexP I heard that Metallic hydrogen still stable after getting released from the enormous pressures it was formed into.

Comment: with CURRENT tech? NoNoNoNONoNO^googlolplex.   (that's not a spelling mistake. a googLOLplex is funny bigger than a googolplex)

Comment: Considering that current Earthling technology is barely able to support one scientific satellite in Jupiter orbit, and a few submersible that can reach the deeper parts of Earth's oceans, I'd say not :-)

Comment: Metallic hydrogen is not believed to be stable below 200 GPa https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.102.224108#:~:text=Abstract,experimental%20capabilities%20(static%20conditions).

Comment: @Slarty real life gets nerfed again >:-(

Comment: Vote to reopen as other question asks it in a different setting of some, presumable alien advanced civilization and their tech. This one is about how humans can do that, based on knowledge of real stuff even if in the future, this question is formulated better and easiier to aproach

Comment: It *is* a decent question. But also a question with the most singular emphatic "no" as the only possible answer. You would need SunDiver class tech to achieve this